# Openni_launch failure / "cannot launch node of type [nodelet/nodelet]"

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, ros-electric, pandaboard

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
I run Ubuntu 11.10 plus ROS electric (installed from source) on an Pandaboard ES and try to use a Kinectsensor with this setup.
But when I fire up following command

$ roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
I get the following kind of failure:

---

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [nodelet/nodelet]: Cannot locate node of type [nodelet] in package
```

---

I tried to rebuild te packages by rosmake tf && rosmake and now i get a different failure message.

---

```
started roslaunch server http://129.73.14.14:53859/

SUMMARY

PARAMETERS * /rosdistro * /camera/driver/rgb_frame_id * /camera/disparity_depth_registered/min_range * /camera/driver/rgb_camera_info_url * /camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth/interpolation * /camera/driver/depth_frame_id * /camera/depth/rectify_depth/interpolation * /camera/disparity_depth/max_range * /rosversion * /camera/driver/device_id 
* /camera/driver/depth_camera_info_url 
* /camera/disparity_depth/min_range 
* /camera/disparity_depth_registered/max_range

NODES 
/camera/depth/ 
rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet) 
metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet) 
metric (nodelet/nodelet) 
points (nodelet/nodelet) 
/camera/rgb/ 
debayer (nodelet/nodelet) 
rectify_mono (nodelet/nodelet) 
rectify_color (nodelet/nodelet) 
/ 
camera_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet) 
camera_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher) 
camera_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher) 
camera_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher) 
camera_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher) 
/camera/ 
driver (nodelet/nodelet) 
register_depth_rgb (nodelet/nodelet) 
points_xyzrgb_depth_rgb (nodelet/nodelet) 
disparity_depth (nodelet/nodelet) 
disparity_depth_registered (nodelet/nodelet) 
/camera/ir/ 
rectify_ir (nodelet/nodelet) 
/camera/depth_registered/ 
rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet) 
metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet) 
metric (nodelet/nodelet)

auto-starting new master 
process[master]: started with pid [11512] 
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311 
2;/home/panda/ros/openni_kinect/openni_launch/launch/openni.launch http://local1 setting /run_id to 5edfdd6c-b0a2-11e1-856e-2e607c264e01 
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [11527] 
started core service [/rosout] 
process[camera_nodelet_manager-2]: started with pid [11539] 
process[camera/driver-3]: started with pid [11540] 
process[camera/rgb/debayer-4]: started with pid [11541] 
process[camera/rgb/rectify_mono-5]: started with pid [11542] 
process[camera/rgb/rectify_color-6]: started with pid [11563] 
process[camera/ir/rectify_ir-7]: started with pid [11577] 
process[camera/depth/rectify_depth-8]: started with pid [11590] 
process[camera/depth/metric_rect-9]: started with pid [11606] 
process[camera/depth/metric-10]: started with pid [11622] 
process[camera/depth/points-11]: started with pid [11634] 
process[camera/register_depth_rgb-12]: started with pid [11647] 
process[camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth-13]: started with pid [11667] 
process[camera/depth_registered/metric_rect-14]: started with pid [11681] 
process[camera/depth_registered/metric-15]: started with pid [11708] 
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_depth_rgb-16]: started with pid [11723] 
process[camera/disparity_depth-17]: started with pid [11736] 
process[camera/disparity_depth_registered-18]: started with pid [11750] 
[camera/rgb/rectify_color-6] process has died [pid 11563, exit code 255]. 
log files: /home/panda/.ros/log/5edfdd6c-b0a2-11e1-856e-2e607c264e01/camera-rgbg [camera/rgb/debayer-4] process has died [pid 11541, exit code 255]. 
log files: /home/panda/.ros/log/5edfdd6c-b0a2-11e1-856e-2e607c264e01/camera-rgbg [camera/ir/rectify_ir-7] process has died [pid 11577, exit code 255]. 
log files: /home/panda/.ros/log/5edfdd6c-b0a2-11e1-856e-2e607c264e01/camera-ir-g process[camera_base_link-19]: started with pid [11774] 
process[camera_base_link1-20]: started with pid [11791] 
[camera/driver-3] process has died [pid 11540, exit code 255]. 
log files: /home/panda/.ros/log/5edfdd6c-b0a2-11e1-856e-2e607c264e01/camera-drig [camera/depth/points-11] process has died [pid 11634, exit code 255]. 
log files: /home/panda/.ros/log/5edfdd6c-b0a2-11e1-856e-2e607c264e01/camera-depg process[camera_base_link2-21]: started with pid [11806] 
[camera/depth/metric_rect-9] process has died [pid 11606, exit code 255]. 
log files: /home/panda/.ros/log/5edfdd6c-b0a2-11e1-856e-2e607c264e01/camera-depg process[camera_base_link3-22]: started with pid [11827] 
[camera/register_depth_rgb-12] process has died [pid 11647, exit code 255]. 
log files: /home/panda/.ros/log/5edfdd6c-b0a2-11e1-856e-2e607c264e01/camera-regg [camera/depth/rectify_depth-8] process has died [pid 11590, exit code 255]. 
log files: /home/panda/.ros/log/5edfdd6c-b0a2-11e1-856e-2e607c264e01/camera-depg [camera/depth_registered/metric-15] process has died [pid 11708, exit code 255]. log files: /home/panda/.ros/log/5edfdd6c-b0a2-11e1-856e-2e607c264e01/camera-depg [camera/points_xyzrgb_depth_rgb-16] process has died [pid 11723, exit code 255]. log files: /home/panda/.ros/log/5edfdd6c-b0a2-11e1-856e-2e607c264e01/camera-poig [camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth-13] process has died [pid 11667, exit co. log files: /home/panda/.ros/log/5edfdd6c-b0a2-11e1-856e-2e607c264e01/camera-depg [camera/disparity_depth-17] process has died [pid 11736, exit code 255]. 
log files: /home/panda/.ros/log/5edfdd6c-b0a2-11e1-856e-2e607c264e01/camera-disg [camera/disparity_depth_registered-18] process has died [pid 11750, exit code 2. log files: /home/panda/.ros/log/5edfdd6c-b0a2-11e1-856e-2e607c264e01/camera-disg [camera/rgb/rectify_mono-5] process has died [pid 11542, exit code 255]. 
log files: /home/panda/.ros/log/5edfdd6c-b0a2-11e1-856e-2e607c264e01/camera-rgbg [camera/depth/metric-10] process has died [pid 11622, exit code 255]. 
log files: /home/panda/.ros/log/5edfdd6c-b0a2-11e1-856e-2e607c264e01/camera-depg [camera/depth_registered/metric_rect-14] process has died [pid 11681, exit code. log files: /home/panda/.ros/log/5edfdd6c-b0a2-11e1-856e-2e607c264e01/camera-depgBlockquoteBlockquote
```

---

This is the output for

$ openni_camera openni_node.launch

```
auto-starting new master 
process[master]: started with pid [980] 
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311 
2;/home/panda/ros/openni_kinect/openni_camera/launch/openni_node.launch http://1 setting /run_id to 52bb505c-af53-11e1-8307-4b990ca55b67 
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [995] 
started core service [/rosout] 
ERROR [1338930820.996429071]: Couldn't find a preferred IP via the getifaddrs. ERROR: cannot launch node of type [openni_camera/openni_node]: Cannot locate no] process[kinect_base_link-3]: started with pid [1007] 
ERROR [1338930821.167174922]: Couldn't find a preferred IP via the getifaddrs. process[kinect_base_link1-4]: started with pid [1008] 
ERROR [1338930821.278625116]: Couldn't find a preferred IP via the getifaddrs. process[kinect_base_link2-5]: started with pid [1020] 
ERROR [1338930821.386413202]: Couldn't find a preferred IP via the getifaddrs. process[kinect_base_link3-6]: started with pid [1031] 
ERROR [1338930821.468139277]: Couldn't find a preferred IP via the getifaddrs.
```

Would be great to get some help.
Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35745/openni_launch-failure-/-%22cannot-launch-node-of-type-%5Bnodelet/nodelet%5D%22/) by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2012-06-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2012-06-05**:
Are you sure that the packages "nodelet" and "tf" are properly installed? You can check for example: rospack find nodelet. It should return something like /opt/ros/electric/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet.

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2012-06-06**:
Thank you for your comment. I checked if they are installed with rospack find nodelet (result : /home/panda/ros/nodelet_core/nodelet) and rospack find tf (result: /home/panda/ros/geometry/tf )

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2012-06-06**:
the different path is probably caused by the installation from source.

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2012-06-06**:
If you installed from source, the error messages make me suspect that the binaries for nodelet and static_transform_publisher are not built. Have you tried rosmake tf && rosmake nodelet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I don't know your purpose of launching openni_launch in specific. But if you just want to get the pointclouds from the kinect. Then you may use

```
roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch
```

I see many posts on

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

doesn't work for many people. I have seen many posts here on the same.
It would be great if these problems are consolidated in a troubleshooting section of the tutorial and make it work at that point.
Any solution regarding the openni.launch is appreciated.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0